# How to make CupertinoActivityIndicator top of every layout?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to make CupertinoActivityIndicator top of every layout?
i need to show progress bar on when login and home page loading time

Comment: You have to use Stack Widget and manage its visibility

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could show a dialog like this:

```
void _showIndicator() {
    showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
    );
  }
```

In this example, I am using CircularProgressIndicator, but you could replace that with CupertinoActivityIndicator. When you want to dismiss the indicator, call:

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```